# Java Reading JSON from http request on php - Bad Request 400

Tags: java, php, json

Im willing to read a simple json file from a http request.
This is the URL im tryng to read:

http://tccdahora.servehttp.com/teste.php

So, ive got a method to convert a URL into JSON, however its not working, ive tryed many different ways or gettin a header on post, however no success.

This is the method:

```
public static JSONArray getPostJSONObject(String url) throws Throwable {

    // faz o POST na pagina php e obtem o inputstream de resposta
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); // "http://tccdahora.servehttp.com/teste.php"
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    httppost.setHeader("host", url);
    //httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

    // transforma o que o php printar em uma strigzona
    JSONArray jArray;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

    String line = "0";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    String result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("", result);
    // transformando em uma array de objetos JSON
    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    return jArray;
}
```

Is there something i am doing wrong ? Im recieving bad request error, and the string from the post is returning a HTML CODE informing the error, not the json as my browser shows.

Thanks alot for the attention !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line:

```
httppost.setHeader("host", url);
```